# Renew a B1/B2 Visa

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, us-visa

I was **accepted** last year for 6 months for B1/B2 Visa, **after being rejected** for the same type of visa and the same reason for travel a month prior that under Section 214(b).
The purpose was to attend a fully funded conference in the US as a student. i got the visa on the second time with 6 months of validity. This year i have got accepted to attend the same conference in the same period of the year, so i have to re-apply again for B1/B2 Visa. 
My main problem is that i am **graduating** 2 months before the conference and this could be a reason for them to reject my application regardless that i have travelled to the US before or not.
 (As i know, if you are a fresh grad, with no travel experience, they think that you will be seeking a job and willing to overstay and you will be rejected)

Comment: @TomasBy It's country-specific based on visa reciprocity.

Comment: I renewed my USA visa three months after graduation when I had not started a job and before mandatory national service in my country.

So It’s not **automatic** that you’ll be denied.

Comment: It is somewhat unusual for a US B visa to be issued for six months. Are you certain it has expired?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot predict what the immigration officer will think, but ...:

Why are you are attending such conference?

You are right about it seems "job seeking", but I think it is also the purpose of such conferences: to get in contact to many people for collaboration or to look for job/PhD, etc. This doesn't mean you will search a job in US or you will not return.  In fact, to me, it seems that you are very interested in the field, so your interest is also not to ruin your career with an overstay. Being fully funded (by your institution?) is also a good sign that you are a good student, so you can apply later as qualified workforce.

Personally I would not see problems. But this has also to do with my initial question. You should have a clear view on what you are looking for on such conference, and have some plans (so no answering with "hmmm", "I do not know", ... on the thing you should really planed).